# Join table on date condition occurring after From table date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a reviews table and a transactions table. I want to find out the number of transactions after a customer submits a review.

Review table looks something like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| customer_id | review_score | review_date | transaction_id |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| 123         | 4            | 2019-01-01  | 894            |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| 123         | 9            | 2019-05-23  | 897            |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| etc         | etc          | etc         | etc            |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Transactions table looks something like this:

```
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| customer_id | transaction_date | transaction_id |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| 123         | 2019-10-01       | 901            |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| 123         | 2019-12-04       | 903            |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| etc         | etc              | etc            |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
```

I would like to see the following:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| customer_id | review_score | review_date | transaction_id | customer_id | transaction_date | transaction_id |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| 123         | 4            | 2019-01-01  | 894            | null        | null             | null           |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| 123         | 9            | 2019-05-23  | 897            | 123         | 2019-10-01       | 901            |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| 123         | 9            | 2019-05-23  | 897            | 123         | 2019-12-04       | 903            |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| etc         | etc          | etc         | etc            | etc         | etc              | etc            |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+
```

The transactions are made after the latest review submitted. There will be instances a customer makes multiple purchases and submit reviews for them. I would like to join the transaction after review submitted and before the next review submitted.

My query:

```
with review_cte as (
    select transaction_id
    , customer_id
    , review_date
    , lead(review_date, 1) over (partition by customer_id order by review_date) as review_date_lead
    , review_score
    from review
)
select rev.*
    , b.transaction_id
    , b.customer_id
    , b.transaction_date
from review_cte as rev
join booking b
    on b.unique_customer_id = rev.customer_id
    and b.transaction_date > rev.review_date
    and b.transaction_date < rev.review_date_lead
    and b.booking_id <> rev.booking_id
order by rev.customer_id, rev.review_date
    , b.customer_id, b.transaction_date
;
```

The problem with my query is that it will either not return all rows or join on the review transaction id more than once because it satisfies the condition where transaction date is > review date. I say depends because I've been experimenting by taking out some join conditions and things like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
select rev.*,
       b.transaction_id, b.customer_id, b.transaction_date
from (select r.*,
             lead(review_date) over (partition by customer_id order by review_date) as next_review_date
      from review r
     ) r left join
     booking b
     on b.unique_customer_id = r.customer_id and
        b.transaction_date > r.review_date and
        (b.transaction_date < r.review_date_lead or r.review_date_lead is null
        ) and
        b.booking_id <> r.booking_id
order by r.customer_id, r.review_date, b.customer_id, b.transaction_date;
```